# How to find fields sent using POST or GET using chrome or firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, curl

I am trying to login to a website using curl.So I want to know how can I find the fields being sent by the form on the page.

Is there any special addon I can use.I read on google that you can use Ctrl+Shift+I but then where can I see it.I see only this

[image]

And for firefox?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I, then choose "Network" and try to find the request sent when you log in. In firefox you'd use the Firebug addon and do something similar

Comment: With firefox you can use either [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or the webdevelopment tools (menu Tools -> Web development)

Comment: You said "use cURL", so the login process is in another site or in your own website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using chrome developer tools, go to network tab.

Then find the first request file which is usually the index or something similar.

The GET variables can be seen on the Request Headers. While the POST parameters can be found in the form body, right below.

Example of a POST form request in chrome:

[image]

Example of a GET request from stackoverflow site:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the header information in the network tab.

[image: Were to look]